# Web scraping in Python for loop issue doesn't return expected data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having an issue scraping the F1 website using `BeautifulSoup` where I have specified the data I have required using a for loop from the website however I am only retrieving one result instead of all the results within the class.

Below is my following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

page = requests.get("https://www.formula1.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_="race-list")

for container in data:
    countryname = container.find_all("span", class_="name")
    country = countryname[0].text
    racetype = container.find_all("span", class_="race-type")
    rtype = racetype[0].text
    racetime = container.find_all("time", class_="day")
    racetimename = racetime[0].text.replace("\n", "").strip()
    print(country)
```

My Current Output -

```
Australia
```

Expected Output -

```
Australia

Bahrain

China

etc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the HTML elements you expect are actually received? Try finding them manually in the parsed tree, because it could easily be a dynamically loaded page, where you're better off with Selenium than BeautifulSoup+Requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit:

```
country = countryname[0].text
```

The reason:

There are 21 countries and you're only fetching the first one at `zeroth` index i.e.

`country = countryname[0].text`

The answer:

Loop through the 'countryname' to find all the elements:

```
  import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

page = requests.get("https://www.formula1.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_="race-list")
#
# print(data)

for container in data:
  countryname = container.find_all("span", class_="name")
  for count in countryname:
      country = count.text
      racetype = container.find_all("span", class_="race-type")
      rtype = count.text
      racetime = container.find_all("time", class_="day")
      racetimename = count.text.replace("\n", "").strip()
      print(country)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Australia
Bahrain
China
Azerbaijan
Spain
Monaco
Canada
France
Austria
Great Britain
Germany
Hungary
Belgium
Italy
Singapore
Russia
Japan
Mexico
United States
Brazil
Abu Dhabi
```

Comment: No need to use `range()` nor `len()` nor indexed access, just iterate over `countryname` (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Ah, Good catch. Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Thanks, how would I add in the racetype and racename, so that the data would look like Australia, Qualifying, Sat ?

Comment: append them in the `print` statement like: `print(country, ", ", racetype)`

Comment: Or use tring formatting: `print("{}, {}, {}".format(country, racetype, racetimename))`